# PHP Mysql Check the row and how many have the same email

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have this problem on PHP MYSQL
this is my database sample

```
id word email
1  Helo jon@gmail.com
2  Sim  jon@gmail.com
3  Sam  jon@gmail.com
4  Mac  mars@gmail.com
5  Mimic mars@gmail.com
```

now what i was trying to solve here is that how can i count the email with same email for example
OUTPUT web page :

```
id word email          submitted words dictionary
1  Helo jon@gmail.com        3         regular
2  Sim  jon@gmail.com        3         regular
3  Sam  jon@gmail.com        3         regular
4  Mac  mars@gmail.com       2         regular
5  Mimic mars@gmail.com      2         regular
```

the submitted words is the count of the email.
how can i work it out on php to count the same email and output 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS nb_emails
FROM your_table
GROUP BY `email`
```

It will return for each email in your table the number of associated records.

If you are using [mysql_* functions](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php), you may fetch all values using that code:

```
$sql = "SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS nb_emails
          FROM your_table
          GROUP BY `email`";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    // do something with the values of the last fetched record. The values are stored in $row['email'] and $row['nb_emails']
}
```

Note: Use of the MySQL extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Comment: how can i fetch it? `$row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )` is that correct then $row['nb_emails'];

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_num_rows()` For example:

```
//mysql_connect() & mysql_select_db()    
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE email='jon@gmail.com'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($q); //3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Word, a.Email, b.SubmittedWords
FROM   myTable a INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT email, COUNT(*) SubmittedWords
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY email
        ) b
            ON a.email = b.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select email,
count(email) as count_same
from table_users
group by email
having ( count(email) > 1 );
```